# How to convert the object of character to string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got this object of characters:

```
Resource {0: "-", 1: "-", 2: "-", 3: "-",  4: "-", 5: "B", 6: "E", 7: "G", 8: "I", 9: "N", 10: " ", 11: "C", 12: "E", 13: "R", 14: "T", 15: "I", .... }
```

and want to convert it to this

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

This is certificate. Is there a way to do this in javascript
Thanks
-k

Comment: You'd be better off just going with a PGP encryption library... But yes, you also need to show some effort. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: If the whitespace is irrelevant: `$.grep(Object.values(Resource), Boolean).join("");`

Answer (score 1):

Your object of characters is already *almost* an array. It has numeric indices, but is missing the `.length` property. If you add that it, it will be an "array like" object, which can then be passed to [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to get a proper array.

Once you have a real array, all you need to do to reconstruct the string is to join the array using empty string:

```js
const obj = {0: "-", 1: "-", 2: "-", 3: "-",  4: "-", 5: "B", 6: "E", 7: "G", 8: "I", 9: "N", 10: " ", 11: "C", 12: "E", 13: "R", 14: "T", 15: "I"};

// Needs a length key to turn it into an "array-like":
obj.length = Object.keys(obj).length;
console.log(Array.from(obj).join(""));
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. That's exactly what I want. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Hi there. The method "from" didn't work on IE. Is there any other method that can work to all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the object to an array and join it for a string.

```js
var resource = { 0: "-", 1: "-", 2: "-", 3: "-",  4: "-", 5: "B", 6: "E", 7: "G", 8: "I", 9: "N", 10: " ", 11: "C", 12: "E", 13: "R", 14: "T", 15: "I" },
    string = Object.assign([], resource).join('');

console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.keys grabs all the keys within a hash and you can .map() to map all the keys to a your personally defined function

```
var someString =""
var resource = {0: "-", 1: "-", 2: "-", 3: "-",  4: "-", 5: "B", 6: "E", 7: 
"G", 8: "I", 9: "N", 10: " ", 11: "C", 12: "E", 13: "R", 14: "T", 15: "I" }
Object.keys(a).map(function(item){ 
    someString = someString + resource[item]
})
someString;
```